# how to plot the comparison of the overlay bar chart with pgfplot/tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pdftex, overleaf

I have the code to plot the overlay bar chart with pgfplot/tikz. However, I would like to plot another group of data for comparison. Could you give me a hand doing that? That is, I have the overlay bar chart like "I I I", I would like to plot the comparison of the overlay bar chart like "II II II". Hope everything is clear. Thanks!

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar stacked,
        bar width=15pt,
        ymin=0,ymax=300,
        % nodes near coords,
        enlarge x limits=0.15,
        legend style={at={(0.5,1)}, anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
        ylabel={Percentage (\%)},
        ylabel near ticks,
        symbolic x coords={Q1, Q2, Q3},
        xtick=data,
        % x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
        ]
        \addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(Q1, 43) (Q2, 23) (Q3, 14)};
        \addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(Q1, 34) (Q2, 36) (Q3, 39)};
        \addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(Q1, 34) (Q2, 36) (Q3, 39)};
        \addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(Q1, 34) (Q2, 36) (Q3, 39)};
        \addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(Q1, 34) (Q2, 36) (Q3, 39)};
        \legend{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
        \coordinate (A) at (100,143);
        \coordinate (B) at (20,203);
        \end{axis}
        \node at (A) {test};
        \node at (B) {test 2};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{The satisfaction of learning experience with the virtual reality lab.}
    \label{fig:experience}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: You want to plot "the comparison of the overlay bar chart". What is that?